# Merge and Append XML documents using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I would like to merge two XML documents. They are from two distinct web services. Each XML documents states how many books it holds in the  node.
I would like the total of  (from each XML document) to be added and appended to the resulting merged XML document.

PHP code merging the documents:

```
<?php
header('Content-type:  text/xml');

$xmlDom1 = new DOMDocument();
$xmlString = '';
foreach ( file('1.xml') as $node ) {
$xmlString .= trim($node);
}
$xmlDom1->loadXML($xmlString);


$xmlDom2 = new DOMDocument();
$xmlString = '';
foreach ( file('2.xml') as $node ) {
$xmlString .= trim($node);
}
$xmlDom2->loadXML($xmlString);



//merge doms
$xmlRoot = $xmlDom1->documentElement;
foreach ( $xmlDom2->documentElement->childNodes as $node2 ) {
 $node = $xmlDom1->importNode($node2,true);
 $xmlRoot->appendChild($node);
```

} echo $xmlDom1->saveXML();?>

First XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
<NumberOfResult>2</NumberOfResult>
<book>
  <bookid>1</bookid>
  <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
  <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
  <genre>Computer</genre>
  <price>44.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
  <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
  with XML.</description>
   </book>
  <book>
<bookid>2</bookid>
  <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
  <title>Midnight Rain</title>
  <genre>Fantasy</genre>
  <price>5.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
  <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
  an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
  of the world.</description>
 </book>
</catalog>
```

Second XML document:

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
<NumberOfResult>1</NumberOfResult>
<book>
<bookid>3</bookid>
  <author>Galos, Mike</author>
  <title>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
  <genre>Computer</genre>
  <price>49.95</price>
  <publish_date>2001-04-16</publish_date>
  <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
  looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are 
  integrated into a comprehensive development 
  environment.</description>
</book>
</catalog>
```

Comment: Just load the contents of all XML Documents together and cut off the catalog from each the first document's end and all the further documents beginnings and ends. After saving this into one variable, add the catalog closing tag and then simply write it with fwrite() and save as .xml

Comment: Sorry but am a beginner with php and XML - although I understand your logic I am not sure how to achieve it

Answer (score 1):

You got two tasks here. Import the book nodes from several XML documents into one and add the count as element before them.

So first create a target document and add a catalog node:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$catalog = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('catalog'));
```

Next load each source document, fetch the book nodes and import them to the target document.

```
foreach ($xmls as $xml) {
  $srcDom = new DOMDocument();
  $srcDom->loadXml($xml);
  $xpath = new DOMXpath($srcDom);
  foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/catalog/book') as $book) {
    $catalog->appendChild($dom->importNode($book, TRUE));
  }
}
```

Now that all book nodes are in the target document, you can use Xpath to count them.

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$count = $dom->createElement('NumberOfResult');
$count->appendChild(
  $dom->createTextNode(
    $xpath->evaluate('count(/catalog/books)')
  )
);
$catalog->insertBefore($count, $catalog->firstChild);
```

Live Demo: https://eval.in/135143

Answer (score -1):

Save the content of your XML documents into variables, e.g. $xmlDocument1, 2, 3...

Use str_replace (http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.str-replace.php) and delete  from the first document.

```
$output_new = str_replace("</catalog>", "", $xmlDocument1);
```

Then use it for each (use for each!) to remove it from every further document (or just the second one):

```
$output_new = $output_new . str_replace("<catalog>", "", $xmlDocument[$i]);
$output_new = $output_new . str_replace("</catalog>", "", $xmlDocument[$i]);
```

$i is the value you set in your for each which shall increase +1 every loop.

At the end, add :

```
$output_new = $output_new . '</catalog>';
```

And last but not least, write it to a new .xml file:

```
$xmlDocument_new = fopen("merged.xml","w");
fwrite($xmlDocument_new, $output_new);
```

You can also shorten the upper str_replace (in the loop) with an array but I think this is better visualized for you. Give it a try. Good luck!

Comment: Many thanks, am trying it now. But how do I read the two <NumberOfResult> as I need to add them to put in the new doc